# RequireJS Optimizer from mainConfigFile not working

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, requirejs, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-requirejs

I am using [grunt-requirejs](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-requirejs) and my app structure looks like this:

```
site/
  dev/
    index.html
    config.coffee
    app.coffee
    etc.
  srv_dev/
    index.html
    config.js
    app.js
    etc.
  dist/
  node_modules/
  Gruntfile.coffee
```

When I run `grunt dev` files get compiled to js from coffee among other tasks and copied from dev/ to srv_dev/ and then are served from there.

My `grunt dist` task does what `dev` does and then runs a requirejs task, which, I hope, should compile / combine all the main dependancies of my app, but still allow for `require(somevar)` and `define` calls to run later on. Basically I have some parts of my single-page app which dont load until the user clicks on the link to it, which fires off a `requrire()` and `define()` call.

My current problem seems quite basic... I have set up my requirejs grunt task as follows:

```
requirejs:
  options:
    baseUrl: './'
    mainConfigFile: 'srv_dev/config.js'
  dist:
    options:
      out: 'dist/script.js'
```

This throws `Error: Error: Missing either a "name", "include" or "modules" option`

I have read most of the optimizer docs as well as the [example build file](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js) and don't understand what is going on with this error. tkellen in [this project](https://github.com/tkellen/streetsmap/blob/master/Gruntfile.coffee) uses the name option for almond.js -- but I don't think I want to do that, because I need those lazy - loader require() calls. The example build file states: "Just specifying a module name means that module will be converted into a built file that contains all of its dependencies." So that was my next attempt:

```
requirejs:
  options:
    baseUrl: './'
    name: 'srv_dev/config.js'
  dist:
    options:
      out: 'dist/script.js'
```

With this I get `Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory >> '/Users/user/Desktop/project/site/app.js'`

So it finds config.js, but then can't find the paths listed in the config, because it using the baseUrl of the require.js config.

And if I specify the baseUrl of './srv_dev' in the requirejs task config then it cant find my config.js file. I have tried a variety of paths to get this to work with no luck. I think the gruntfile needs to be in the same dir as the config.js file, but thats not how my project is set up.

Thanks Folks !!!

Here is the full text of my config.coffee file

```
config =

  baseUrl: './'

  paths:
    # require plugins
    text             : '/components/requirejs-plugins/lib/text'
    json             : '/components/requirejs-plugins/src/json'

    # lib
    jquery           : '/components/jquery/jquery'
    bootstrap        : '/components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap'
    lodash           : '/components/lodash/dist/lodash'
    backbone         : '/components/backbone/backbone'
    marionette       : '/components/marionette/lib/backbone.marionette.min'
    handlebars       : '/components/handlebars/handlebars'
    prism            : '/components/customPrism/prism'
    coffeescript     : '/components/coffee-script/extras/coffee-script'

    # app
    app              : '/app/app'
    appSettings      : '/app/appSettings'
    AppController    : '/app/AppController'
    AppRouter        : '/app/AppRouter'

    postMasterRecord : '/posts/postMasterRecord'

    util             : '/scripts/util'
    templates        : '/templates'
    handlebarsHelpers: '/scripts/handlebarsHelpers'

  shim:
    # lib
    bootstrap:
      deps: ['jquery']
    backbone:
      deps: ['lodash', 'jquery']
      exports: 'Backbone'
    marionette:
      deps: ['backbone', 'lodash', 'jquery']
      exports : 'Marionette'
    handlebars:
      exports: 'Handlebars'
    templates:
      deps: ['handlebars']

    # app
    app:
      deps: [
        'marionette'
        'bootstrap'
        'handlebars'
        'templates'
      ]

  # deps: ['app']

require.config(config)

require(['app'])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is perfectly acceptable to specify the same file as your `mainConfigFile` and for `name` so:

```
requirejs:
  options:
    mainConfigFile: 'srv_dev/config.js'
    baseUrl: './srv_dev'
    name: 'config'
    findNestedDependencies: true
  dist:
    options:
      out: 'dist/script.js'
```

`mainConfigFile` tells `r.js` "here is where you can find my runtime configuration", whereas `name` says "here is my main module". One does not imply the other.

Without `mainConfigFile` `r.js` cannot find your runtime configuration. Without `name` (or `include` or `modules`), it cannot know what the entry point of your application is.

`findNestedDependencies: true` is required for `r.js` to follow the `require([app])` in your `config.js` file.

Comment: Using the code you have provided results in a dist/script.js which looks exactly like my original config file. None of the dependancies declared in it are added to the output file. I have added my config.coffee file to the question so that you can see the structure. Maybe I should use app.js as my 'name' instead ?? Thanks :)

Comment: So its using baseUrl: './' from the grunt-require-options instead of the baseUrl: './' inside of the config.coffee file, which is inside of srv_dev. Basically its looking for the deps as siblings of gruntfile instead of siblings of the config

Comment: So now I'm in this mess where it either looks for config in site/srv_dev/srv_dev/config.js if baseUrl is './srv_dev' or in site/config.js if { baseUrl: './srv_dev', name: 'config.js' } I can't get it to look in site/srv_dev/config.js for some reason.

Comment: Yes, it currently looks like this baseUrl: './srv_dev' name: 'config.js' and it looks for config as a sibling of srv_dev, not inside of it.

Comment: Okay, getting closer, thanks for your help... but now if you look at how app.js is loaded in my config, it is looking for app now in srv_dev/app.js instead of following the path decleration, as srv_dev/app/app.js

Comment: I think `r.js` is having trouble finding your configuration in the `config.js` file. I've never had problems with this but it seems that `r.js` is picky about what [it accepts](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js#L27). Based on what I read there, you'd have to call `require.config` with a literal object instead of passing a variable.

Comment: So basically all of my paths are totally messed up now... its annoying that r.js has different requirements than what works pre-optimization. Anyway, thanks for your help again... right now, because my app.js file requires '../modules/mainNav/loader' and it is not properly relativizing the path for app.js ... its looking for modules as a sibling of srv_dev instead of inside of it. Basically the baseUrl gets used instead of relativizing to the location of app.js in my file system ... which is something I relied heavily upon. :(

Comment: Okay, I've got it all good now, I was being stupid for a bit yesterday. Thanks so much!!

Comment: Great! I did not perform as well as I could have either. There were some steps in the back and forth that could have been skipped if I had not been splitting my attention. (Missing the `.js` suffix, for instance. Argh!)